# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016: Cannot set task/phonecall statecode to 'Completed'

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

When using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 OData API, I ran into a problem
creating a task/phonecall with statecode equal to completed.

Problem Description:

1. create a phone call entity with statecode=1 (Completed) 
                                    statuscode=2 (Made)
    same idea with task (constants defined [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531157.aspx))
2. API returns an internal server error saying that:

> 2 is not a valid status code for state code PhoneCallState.Open on phonecall with Id cfdb5757-3666-e611-80fa-3863bb2ed1f8.

Dynamics server ignored the PhoneCallState.Completed (statecode = 1) parameter
  that I passed to it.
  For now, the workaround is to make a separate PATCH request to update the statecode and statuscode.

Is there a way to create a task/phonecall with completed state in one request?

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: It would have been nice if the api allowed this statecode to be set on POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can create a record in a completed status (`statecode`). So you will need to do a create call followed by an update or set state, I think that is just the way CRM works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that James's answer is correct.  If you truly wanted to perform a single create, and create it as Completed, you could add two new fields to the Entity (PostCreateStatus, PostCreateState) and then create a Post Create Plugin that updates the status and state.  This would be result in a single call to the server, creating the entity with the desired states and statuses.